# Jquery. I have achieved the effect I wanted, but I just want it to work on the homepage

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm currently making my second website and I am using Jquery for the first time. I wanted to make a succession of 4 small squares on the side of my page fade in, in a sequenced order when you load the homepage.

I have managed to do this! It looks great but I don't want the effect to happen each time the viewer clicks on a different page.

If anyone could tell me how to code this animation just so it fades in on my index page I would be extremely grateful.

my current code is listed below,

Many thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.wrapper').fadeIn(1000);

  $("#BlockOne").fadeIn('slow');

  $("#BlockTwo").fadeIn(2500);

  $("#BlockThree").fadeIn(2500);

  $("#BlockFour").fadeIn('slow');

});
```

Comment: It's easy to test the page but why do you put this script on all pages ?

Comment: Is there a particular element that appears on the home page but not any other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to resolve this.

You could simply not output this javascript on pages other than the homepage.  If you need the functionality to make hidden elements appear on the other pages, you could just do an alternate javascript that displays them immediately without the `fadeIn`.

You could output one common function on all pages, but use a condition on the document location to determine whether to fade in or show immediately.

You could save some value in a cookie, or HTMLS localStorage or session storage to act as a flag to determine whether to show with fade in or immediately.

I personally prefer the latter as what happens is the user doesn't arrive to your site via the homepage? I would think your intent would be to have the fade in effect on the first visited page, not necessarily the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a script block on the home page only. **presumably** All other pages will need separate css to make sure you can always see the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Define the code in a click event handler of the button and use **.one** to bind it.

Then **trigger the click** event .. Looks like it works..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire only once..
    $('button').one('click', function() {
        $('.wrapper').fadeIn(1000);
        $("#BlockOne").fadeIn('slow');
        $("#BlockTwo").fadeIn(2500);
        $("#BlockThree").fadeIn(2500);
        $("#BlockFour").fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $('button').click();
});​
```